# Create data frame with all possible combinations of vectors x and y?

Tags: r

I have 2 vectors, `x` and `y`:

```
x <- seq(from=21.6, to=22, by=0.01)
y <- seq(from=58.77, to=58.93, by=0.01)
```

I want to create a data frame `df1<-data.frame(x,y)` with all the possible combinations of `x` and `y`. How can I do this?

Comment: exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

We can use `expand.grid` to get all the possible combinations between the two vectors.

```
expand.grid(x,y)
```